# Json_decode shows empty value

Tags: php

I got a joomla database with a field that has multiple image paths. I want to seperate those paths and read them using json_decode. But when I try my code the image source is empty (where I want the path to be shown)

How I get the data and use json_decode:

```
$content            = "SELECT * FROM `snm_content` WHERE catid = 13";
$contentcon         = $conn->query($content);
$contentcr          = array();
while ($contentcr[] = $contentcon->fetch_array());

$image = json_decode($content['images'], true);
```

I got the following line inside a foreach:

```
<img src="'.$image['image_intro'].'" alt="" class="company_logo">
```

I don't get any output in the img src. Why is that?

This is how I start the foreach if this is relevant:

```
foreach($contentcr as $content)
    {
```

Output of $contentcr:

```
" [6]=> string(1) "1" ["state"]=> string(1) "1" [7]=> string(2) "13" ["catid"]=> string(2) "13" [8]=> string(19) "2015-11-20 08:56:29" ["created"]=> string(19) "2015-11-20 08:56:29" [9]=> string(3) "361" ["created_by"]=> string(3) "361" [10]=> string(0) "" ["created_by_alias"]=> string(0) "" [11]=> string(19) "2015-11-30 11:00:10" ["modified"]=> string(19) "2015-11-30 11:00:10" [12]=> string(3) "361" ["modified_by"]=> string(3) "361" [13]=> string(3) "361" ["checked_out"]=> string(3) "361" [14]=> string(19) "2015-12-02 10:49:59" ["checked_out_time"]=> string(19) "2015-12-02 10:49:59" [15]=> string(19) "2015-11-20 08:56:29" ["publish_up"]=> string(19) "2015-11-20 08:56:29" [16]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["publish_down"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" [17]=> string(209) "{"image_intro":"images\/mobieleairco\/Airco_blog.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}" ["images"]=> string(209) "{"image_intro":"images\/mobieleairco\/Airco_blog.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}" [18]=> string(121) "{"urla":false,"urlatext":"","targeta":"","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}" ["urls"]=> string(121) "{"urla":false,"urlatext":"","targeta":"","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}" [19]=> string(593) "{"show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_layout":"","show_publishing_options":"","show_article_options":"","show_urls_images_backend":"","show_urls_images_frontend":""}" ["attribs"]=> string(593) "{"show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_layout":"","show_publishing_options":"","show_article_options":"","show_urls_images_backend":"","show_urls_images_frontend":""}" [20]=> string(2) "14" ["version"]=> string(2) "14" [21]=> string(1) "3" ["ordering"]=> string(1) "3" [22]=> string(22) "€ 50 (vanaf 2 weken)" ["metakey"]=> string(22) "€ 50 (vanaf 2 weken)" [23]=> string(5) "Slang" ["metadesc"]=> string(5) "Slang" [24]=> string(1) "1" ["access"]=> string(1) "1" [25]=> string(1) "0" ["hits"]=> string(1) "0" [26]=> string(53) "{"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}" ["metadata"]=> string(53) "{"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}" [27]=> string(1) "0" ["featured"]=> string(1) "0" [28]=> string(1) "*" ["language"]=> string(1) "*" [29]=> string(0) "" ["xreference"]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> array(60) { [0]=> string(2) "10" ["id"]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(2) "69" ["asset_id"]=> string(2) "69" [2]=> string(16) "Aelia 12 (AL-12)" ["title"]=> string(16) "Aelia 12 (AL-12)" [3]=> string(14) "aelia-12-al-12" ["alias"]=> string(14) "aelia-12-al-12" [4]=> string(297) "
```

Comment: `$content` "is" the query string, not an array. You assign the fetched record to $contentcr[].

Comment: Alright so a correct line would be: `$image = json_decode($contentcr['images'], true);` ? This still returns empty though.

Comment: try to var_dump() your $contentcr to see what's in it

Comment: json_decode...parse array to json not to a string or any value

Comment: @jayxhj This shows the whole array, including the image paths.

Comment: $content['images'] contain any array ??

Comment: @twan place the output in your question

Comment: why you make while when you can set just $contentcr = $contentcon->fetch_array();

Comment: @jayxhj I added part of the output, because it's a very big array.

Comment: @ParthChavda Yes this contains the array with all the image paths (intro_image, full_image etc etc)

Comment: <img src=" . '/' . '.$image['image_intro'].'" alt="" class="company_logo">

Comment: I get a warning for dividing by zero with that line @jayxhj

Comment: @twan https://3v4l.org/VFPp2

Comment: @jayxhj Yes, that is what I need. But how to read the path?

Comment: $arr = json_decode($json_str, true); $path = $arr['image_intro']; you'd better read the manual compeletely.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable names where confusing matters, but the answer that you where calling `json_decode` on the sql string, not the row:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `snm_content` WHERE catid = 13";
$result = $conn->query($content);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){

    $image = json_decode($row['images'], true);
    echo '<img src="'.$image['image_intro'].'" alt="" class="company_logo">';

}
```

Comment: This is essentialy the same as what I did, but instead of using $content using $contentcr, If i'm correct. I got a lot more information in the foreach so this is not really what I am looking for. All the information is read correctly matching the correct ID, so it's only a matter of getting the image path using json_decode.

Comment: @twan no, its not the same. Your code builds a multidimentional  array called `$contentcr` containing multiple rows, each containing every field in the table (twice). Did you try the above code

Comment: Yeah I added the code, but it still shows an empty source.